# element.startIndex is undefined when using withStartIndices option in Cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

When using Cheerio to parse HTML, I want the `startIndex` of the node, so I use the following code to instruct Cheerio to add that property per the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#loading) and [here](https://github.com/fb55/DomHandler#option-withstartindices):

```
const options = { withStartIndices: true };

const html = `
<template>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</template>
<script>
  const foo = () => {
    console.log('bar')
  }
</script>
<style>
  h1{
    color:blue;
  }
</style>
`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html, { withStartIndices: true });
console.log( $('#element')[0].startIndex );
```

But this results in the following output:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

After searching online and digging through Cheerio's code, I found that Cheerio is using [parse5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse5) by default. In order to get the `startIndex` property, you have to instruct Cheerio to use [htmlparser2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) by setting the `xmlMode` option to `true`:

```
const options = {
  xmlMode: true,
  withStartIndices: true
}

const html = `
<template>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</template>
<script>
  const foo = () => {
    console.log('bar')
  }
</script>
<style>
  h1{
    color:blue;
  }
</style>
`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html, options);
console.log( $('#element')[0].startIndex );
```

This results in the following output:

```
110
```

Hurray!

Comment: Unable to use withStartIndices: true in latest cheerios i install it with using npm i cheerio can u please tell me at which version this will work

Comment: It seems to be working for me in `v0.22.0`. What version are you trying with?

Comment: "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3"  i also use typescript @types/cheerio because of typescript may be its (withStartIndices) not working......when i tried without @types/cheerio  it works is it the issue with @types/cheerio ??

Comment: In this case, what does "not working" mean? Is there a Typescript error, or an actual functional difference when you run the code?

Comment: it gives the error that withStartIndices property not exists at compile time

Comment: Turns out that option was mistakenly left out of the type definitions in `@types/cheerio`. I've created a Pull Request (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/43863) to rectify this. Until that PR is accepted, you should be able to do something like `const $ = cheerio.load(html, { withStartIndices: true } as unknown as any)`.